# Finding Probabilities Using The Binomial Model

Tags: options, option-pricing, probability

I was not able to find a similar question when searching, but if I've missed one please feel free to point me to it. Unfortunately the closest example in the textbook was not terribly helpful either.

I am working on a problem that asks me to make use of the binomial model for discrete time option valuation with the objective of finding the probability that a call option finishes "in the money," which is to say $S - K > 0$ where $S$ is the security value and $K$ is the strike price of the option. The problem doesn't say anything else, so I believe I want a general probability in terms of $p$ and $q$.

We have primarily used the binomial model to determine the *value* of securities and options up to this point, so I'm not sure exactly where to start to find the probability.

The formulation we have used was of this form:

$V_0 = (1 + i)^{-N}E(F(S_n))$

$ = (1 + i)^{-N} \sum_{j=0}^N {N \choose j} \times (S_0 \times u^j \times d^{N-j}) \times p^j \times q^{N-j}$

Where $u$ and $d$ are the factors by which a security increases or decreases in value each period.

I started by taking this model and replacing $F(S_n)$ with $F(S_n - K)$. But thinking about it that seems to only get me the expected value. If I just focus on the probability component, which is just binomial we have $p^j * q^{N-j}$ for any given event, but with knowing the other parameters I dont know how I am supposed to find out when the option is in the money or not (for example, this would depend on the values of $u$ and $d$).

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just deal with the aspect of probabilities. The answer is easier than you think.

Consider the simplest one-step model. At the end, the stock will either be up (to $Su$) or down (to $Sd$). It will move up with a probability p or down with a probability (1-p). Here's how to calculate p:

$ p = \frac {e^{rT} - d}{u - d} $

For example, consider a stock (from *Hull*), where $ u = 1.1, d=0.9, r=0.12, T $ is 3 months.

$ p = \frac {e^{0.12 \times 0.25} - 0.9}{1.1 - 0.9} = 0.6523 $

Now consider a two-step model. The stock will end up in one of three states.

1. uu
2. ud or du
3. dd

Note that because multiplication is commutative, $S \times d \times u = S \times u \times d$, and we got to state 2 through 1 down and 1 up, not caring whether the down or the up came first. (This is a *recombining* tree. If we have dividends, the tree does not recombine and it becomes more complex.)

The probabilities that each of the states will occur will correspondingly be:

1. $1 \times p^2$
2. $2 \times p \times (1-p)$
3. $1 \times (1-p)^2$

Why the factors 1, 2, 1 at the beginning? These correspond to the different paths to get there, namely {uu}, {ud, du}, {dd} having a set size of 1, 2, and 1.

The three-step model will have four final states.

1. 3 u / 0 d: $1 \times p^3$
2. 2 u / 1 d: $3 \times p^2 \times (1-p)$
3. 1 u / 2 d: $3 \times p \times (1-p)^2$
4. 0 u / 3 d: $1 \times (1-p)^3$

The factors 1, 3, 3, 1 correspond to the different paths to get to the final states, namely

1. {uuu}
2. {uud, udu, duu}
3. {udd, dud, ddu}
4. {ddd}

The multipliers are the *choose* function that you described in your question. Another way to think of this is through Pascal's Triangle.

```
    1
   1 1
  1 2 1
 1 3 3 1
1 4 6 4 1
```

Once you understand the pattern, it should be fairly easy to extend.

There's a much better graph than I can draw at [image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Arbre_Binomial_Options_Reelles.png], and no discussion of binomial option trees would be complete without it. While there are 3 paths to get to each of the middle boxes at the far right, there is only 1 path to get to the top box.

Answer (score 2):

First find minimum value of j that assures the option is in the money.  This would be function of u,d,n,S,K,p,q

Any particular value of j has a probability associated with it.  You gave formula above.  Then you need sum probabilities from j=min j needed to n.  See wikipedia binomial distribution to find formula for sum. Sum is based on cdf of binomial distribution.  cdf is not closed form.